# send notification acknowledgement received from xmpp protocol from javascript client

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-push

I am using firebase xmpp protocol to send web push notification to client but not getting any receipt for the same weather message is received or not.

How to send acknowledgement from my javascript client (maybe from service worker file or from js file) so that i can record that how many notification were sent successfully.